how to avoid spaces while using payload
I am trying to use this payload to pass it into python post request. However while doing that, it sends the payload with spaces between fields. This is causing http 400. How to avoid this in python.
payload = {"start_time":f"{start}","end_time":f"{end}","filter":{"site":f"{site}","element":f"{elementid}"},"interval":"5min","metrics":[{"name":"CPUUsage","statistics":["max"],"unit":"percentage"}],"view":{"summary":True},}
print("payload data: ", payload)

Output:
payload data:  {'start_time': '2024-09-19T16:29:37.607', 'end_time': '2024-09-19T16:24:37.607', 'filter': {'site': '16970975636546', 'element': '1569874521567'}, 'interval': '5min', 'metrics': [{'name': 'CPUUsage', 'statistics': ['max'], 'unit': 'percentage'}], 'view': {'summary': True}}

I dont need any spaces in the payload output.

    def get_sys_metrics(self):
# has to be called immediately after bearer token
        api_endpoint = "/sdwan/monitor/v2.3/api/monitor/sys_metrics"
        full_url = f"{self.api_sase_url}{api_endpoint}"
        url = "https://api.sase.paloaltonetworks.com/sdwan/monitor/v2.3/api/monitor/sys_metrics"
# read the file for site and element ids
        with open("elements_id.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as site_element_id:
            d = json.load(site_element_id)
            payloads = []
            for i in d:
                site = i["site_id"]
                elementid = i["element_id"]
                payload = {"start_time":f"{start}","end_time":f"{end}","filter": {"site":f"{site}","element":f"{elementid}"},"interval":"5min","metrics":[{"name":"CPUUsage","statistics":["max"],"unit":"percentage"}],"view":{"summary":True},}
                print("+++++++", payload)
                payloads.append(payload)
# Pass the headers to request body
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.bearer_token}",
        }
# POST request
        for payload in payloads:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False)
            print(response.json())

prisma_obj = PrismaAccess("token", client_id, client_secret, tsg_id)
prisma_obj.get_bearer_token()
elements = prisma_obj.get_sys_metrics()
#Print the metrics
print(elements)


Are you using the Python requests package? If so, how are you calling requests.post()? Are you passing the payload as a dict? Also, are you certain that the issue is related to spaces? can you show us the request response text of the server?

If the API expects JSON, use json=payload in the requests.post() call.

Here is the script... Yes i do use requests..

That code doesn't show how you're sending the payload in the API request. That's what we need to see.

@rocky2012, when you print a dictionary, the Python interpreter adds spaces between the elements just to make it more readable. But your dictionary has no spaces because it is not a string, it is a dictionary. Show us the response of print(response.json()). Probably there we can see the problem.

Hi Joseph,  Here is the response from print(response.json())  {'_etag': 0, '_content_length': '298', '_schema': 0, '_created_on_utc': 0, '_updated_on_utc': 0, '_status_code': '400', '_request_id': '1726844083035001299999114229564923640535', '_error': [{'code': 'SCHEMA_CHECK_FAIL', 'message': '$.filter.element: string found, array expected'}]}

As Barmar suggested before, include information like the response in your question so that we can analyze it more easily.

You’ll want to read about what an http://xyproblem.info is.

The issue is not related to spaces in the dictionary. The problem is that the server you're sending the POST request to requires the value of payload["filter"]["element"] to be an array, not a string. I'm not sure if the server expects this array to be a list or a bytearray for the elementid. it depends on the server's requirements. You should read the server API's documentation or ask the developer.
Try to replace the payload variable assignment with the following:
payload = {
    "start_time": start,
    "end_time": end,
    "filter": {
        "site": [site],
        "element": [elementid],
    },
    "interval": "5min",
    "metrics": [{"name": "CPUUsage", "statistics": ["max"], "unit": "percentage"}],
    "view": {"summary": True},
}


{'_etag': 0, '_content_length': '295', '_schema': 0, '_created_on_utc': 0, '_updated_on_utc': 0, '_status_code': '400', '_request_id': '1726858073293011800003435556221688547143', '_error': [{'code': 'SCHEMA_CHECK_FAIL', 'message': '$.filter.site: string found, array expected'}]}` 

I am getting the same error message.
